# Timer properties not present on Exchange after upgrading to Camel 4.1

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to upgrade from Camel 4.0 to 4.1, and none of the timer properties appear to be on the exchange.  Were these moved somewhere else?   The time does appear to work correctly.

Theses are the properties I am referring to:
https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/timer-component.html

Prior to 4.1, you would be able to access these like so:

```
exchange.getProperty(Exchange.TIMER_NAME, String.class)
exchange.getProperty(Exchange.TIMER_PERIOD, String.class)
```

Using 4.0 I can see the properties are there, but in 4.1 they are simply not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the upgrade guides, where you can find details how to turn this on again
https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-4x-upgrade-guide-4_1.html#_camel_timer

Comment: thanks this is perfect.  for some reason i missed this in the documentation.